# Error al intentar instalar el cliente de Vue

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, npm

Mi procesador, SO, versión de node y npm son:

```
 $ uname -p
x86_64
 $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
 $ node -v
v10.19.0
 $ npm -v
6.14.4
```

Estoy intentando instalar el cliente de vue como root con el verbose para ver el detalle:

```
 $ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --verbose
```

Y camina bien hasta que se tropieza con:

```
...
npm info lifecycle safe-buffer@5.1.2~postinstall: safe-buffer@5.1.2
npm info lifecycle convert-source-map@1.7.0~postinstall: convert-source-map@1.7.0
npm info lifecycle cookie@0.4.0~postinstall: cookie@0.4.0
npm info lifecycle cookie-signature@1.0.6~postinstall: cookie-signature@1.0.6
npm info lifecycle copy-descriptor@0.1.1~postinstall: copy-descriptor@0.1.1
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~postinstall: core-js@3.6.5

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

 $
```

Y se sale al prompt del terminal.

Ejecuto manualmente la intalacion de core-js:

```
$ sudo npm i -g core-js --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'i',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'core-js',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.14.4
npm info using node@v10.19.0
npm verb npm-session bb90059e6a975c40
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js 2232ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js/-/core-js-3.6.5.tgz 3331ms
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 5606ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 2ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 4ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 8ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 3ms
npm verb correctMkdir /root/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-3a08f0df5026584d.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm timing action:extract Completed in 250ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~preuninstall: core-js@3.6.5
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~uninstall: core-js@3.6.5
npm verb unbuild rmStuff core-js@3.6.5 from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~postuninstall: core-js@3.6.5
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 3ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 107ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 1ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 7ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~preinstall: core-js@3.6.5
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 1ms
npm info linkStuff core-js@3.6.5
npm timing action:build Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~install: core-js@3.6.5
npm timing action:install Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle core-js@3.6.5~postinstall: core-js@3.6.5

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


 $
```

Y falla exactamente en el mismo sitio.

En este hilo:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-install-vue-cli-permission-error-in-require-postinstall/82017

Recomiendan hacer esta instalacion:

```
 $ sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm @vue/cli
```

Pero creo que no es la solución óptima.

Alguna idea que me pueda sacar de este atolladero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uno de los motivos por los que sucede esto es por que en el proyecto ya existía un **node_modules** con algunos paquetes que no son compatibles con el nuevo core de vue 2, en mi caso lo solucione simplemente borrado la carpeta node_modules y volviendo a instalar todo.